# Make PHP Web Crawler to Respect the robots.txt file of any website

Tags: robots.txt

I have developed a Web Crawler and now i want to respect the robots.txt file of the websites that i am crawling.

I see that this is the robots.txt file structure:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /~joe/junk.html
Disallow: /~joe/foo.html
Disallow: /~joe/bar.html
```

I can read, line by line and then use explode with space character as delimiter to find data.

Is there any other way that i can load the entire data ?

Does this kind of files have a language, like XPath has ?

Or do i have to interprete the entire file ?

Any help is welcomed, even links, duplicates if found ...

Comment: Hey! I am just curious, how did you solve the user-agent part? You wrote a special regex to match just results from user-agent: * ?

Comment: when i use the cURL, the user agent is already stored in the database, so i know what user agent my cURL algorithm should identify as; peace of cake

Comment: OK, I did the follow, I have to spider each hour 100 websites. I read out the robots.txt once a week, with a regex I take the user agent: * part (including, disallow etc. etc.) till te next user agent if exists. Than I store the paths as an regex pattern in my database for each website. Than I use the regex in my spider to see if I am allowed  to spider the path of links I get. How you think about that? :) Cheers!

Comment: yes i did, but, but i may have to scan 50.000 urls from 1 website daily, so, i will have to bend the robots rules a little bit

Comment: 50.000 urls, that sounds nice. What you do against an possible ip ban?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure is very simple, so the best thing you can do is probably parse the file on your own. i would read it line by line and as you said look for keywords like User-agent, Disallow etc.

Comment: yes, thats what i will do if i dont get a bright answer; i am expecting to get a bright answer, since i found out that XPath has its own language :d; maybe i get lucky and i learn somenthing new

Comment: afaik XPath is XML specific and therefore won't help you much with adressing the nodes in a robots.txt file...